# Column alignment and spacing in tabularx

Tags: tabularx

I have a problem with my tables and I am not sure why. I made this table format a long time ago and wanted to use the same style again. Though I cannot seem to get the leftmost column to behave.

I just want all the columns to be equal and be centered.

```
\begin{table}[!ht]
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X*{4}{c}}
  \hline\\   \multicolumn{4}{c}{\Large Keywords}
  \\
  \hline
  \\
  \large A & \large B & \large C & \large D\\\\ 
  1 & 2 & 3  & 4\\ 

  \hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{test}\label{test}
\end{table}
```

[image]

This is what it looks like now.

How would one go about fixing this? :)

//Bogi

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!! It is better to post a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). For example, A LaTeX MWE should start with a `\documentclass` command, have a minimal preamble  and then `\begin{document}...\end{document}`. Unless the problem is a compilation error, the code should compile and be as small as possible to demonstrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you --- and much more likely that they will!

Comment: The `tabularx` manual states: `Do not use \multicolumn with X` ;-)

Comment: You can also check the less known [`tabulary`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabulary) package with its `C` column-type.

Answer (score 1):

The preamble of your tabularx environment wasn't correct for what you want (you had one X column and 4 centred columns with their natural width). I took the liberty to replace the `\hline`s with rules from the `booktabs` package, which hace some vertical padding around them and a variable width, looking more ‘professional’:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{tabularx, booktabs}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{4}{X}}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{4}{c}{\Large Keywords}
    \\
    \midrule
    \\
    \large A & \large B & \large C & \large D \\\\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
  \caption{test}\label{test}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> I just want all the columns to be equal and be centered.

I suggest you define a centered version of the `X` column type and use it for all four columns.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!ht]
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{4}{C}}
  \hline\\  
  \multicolumn{4}{c}{\Large Keywords}
  \\
  \hline
  \\
  \large A & \large B & \large C & \large D\\[1\baselineskip] 
  1 & 2 & 3  & 4\\ 
  \hline
\end{tabularx}
\caption{test}\label{test}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```